# Postfix suddenly is not configured for MySQL

Tags: postfix

I've had this server in use for something like a week. Fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install, packages all installed through apt. I could receive and send mail outside of my IP just fine. Suddenly, receiving e-mail was not longer possible.

I checked the logs and soon noticed the `error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql` message, which meant that postfix was unable to check the recipient against my database. I checked my `apt list --installed` output, but postfix-mysql was installed, so that wasn't the problem. I soon discovered I needed to add the line:
`mysql /usr/lib/postfix/postfix-mysql.so.1.0.1 dict_mysql_open`
to `/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf` and do a `postfix reload`.

My question is: how could this happen? I do have an `apt update && apt upgrade` cron running that auto-updates the server.

#### Update

The last update I saw was this one:

`2021-09-28 23:01:31 upgrade postfix:amd64 3.4.13-0ubuntu1.1 3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2`
The problems started right after that. `dynamicmaps.cf` was empty except for the commented instruction-line at the top. I added the mysql-line, and now that is the only functional line in the file.

#### Update 2

After killing all the processes found with `ps -Af | grep -E 'dpkg|debconf|apt|unatt'` I ran:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
sudo dpkg --configure -a -D223
```

Which gave me the following error when trying to configure postfix:

```
D000001: process queue pkg postfix-mysql:amd64 queue.len 54 progress 1, try 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postfix-mysql:
 postfix-mysql depends on postfix (= 3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package postfix is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package postfix-mysql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I don't know enough about dpkg to understand this. What's happening here?

### Update 3

`dpkg-query --show --showformat='${package} ${status}\n' 'postfix*'`
yields:

```
postfix install ok installed                                                                                            postfix-cdb unknown ok not-installed
postfix-doc unknown ok not-installed
postfix-ldap unknown ok not-installed
postfix-lmdb unknown ok not-installed
postfix-mysql install ok installed
postfix-pcre unknown ok not-installed
postfix-pgsql unknown ok not-installed
postfix-sqlite unknown ok not-installed
```

So both requested packages are in an OK and installed status. The apt command did not suggest a fix as far as I saw (and I read the output carefully). It seems your suggestions worked.

What I don't like is not knowing what I'm doing, but that is due to my own apt and dpkg lack of knowledge.

Comment: Well, open up your dpkg.log and check after which version you experienced the unexpected change. Also, what were the contents of the `dynamicmaps.cf` file before you edited it?

Comment: Updated the question with the information

Comment: You only added the error, but I was sort of expecting `apt-get install -f` to automatically suggest the solution to the dependency problem for you. What did apt-get say?

Comment: The dpkg-query command I suggested should list the current status of all involved packages.. but its probably less effort to just `apt install postfix postfix-mysql` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks again, updated in Update 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you upgrade a postfix map package, it will first remove its respective map type from `/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf` and only in a later add it (back). You can manually see that this works by forcing a reconfiguration via `dpkg-reconfigure postfix-mysql`. If the file was left empty after the upgrade, **that likely means the upgrade was interrupted - or is even still hanging, waiting for user input that never came.**

If you are applying all SRU, then you will have upgraded Postfix to `3.4.13-0ubuntu1.2` for Ubuntu 20.04. I recommend you confirm that no upgrades are currently being applied:

```sh
ps -Af | grep -E 'dpkg|debconf|apt|unatt'
dpkg-query --show --showformat='${package} ${status}\n' 'postfix*'
```

Your cron job has is flawed in that it fails to tell apt that this is a *non-interactive* invocation, this *may* be the reason it is hanging.

If necessary, ensure all packages are properly installed. During this steps, you will likely see warnings or questions that help determine *why* your cron job failed.

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
sudo dpkg --configure -a -D223
```

Don't forget to remove the offending cron job as setup something reliable. **The program `unattended-upgrade` is usually the preferred method of applying upgrades on Ubuntu systems when no admin is standing by.** It will skip over or use defaults for things apt would otherwise ask for interactively.

Comment: Thanks so much. The ps output gave me a number of results. The one that struck me was: `root      979323  979322  0 Sep28 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c (apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade) > /dev/null`. Sep 28th was the date after which the error occured, I assume this tells me the update process is still hanging?

Comment: Oh that's your cron call, so it seems like its hanging. Look what other processes (specifically: child processes of the one you found) are running - I suspected the upgrade got stuck while calling dpkg/debconf somewhere. If you do not want to fix this, kill the child process, wait for apt to deal with that, then try my steps to ensure you get all packages back to normal.

Comment: Thanks again, updated my question with findings